# Comparison of UI controls between Xamarin.Forms, UWP, and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin.forms, uwp

I'm looking for a document that does a side by side comparison of the C# XAML specifying each of the following Microsoft UI control in the frameworks:

- Xamarin.Forms
- UWP
- WPF

I'm looking for a mapping of controls with similar functions (example, UWP/WPF:stackpanel vs. Xamarin:stacklayout), and that describes the major similarities and differences between similar UI controls, and omissions of UI controls between framework systems.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/desktop/controls/wpf

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/desktop/controls/

Comment: Your question is too broad, if you have found related document, please feel free post in your answer, appreciate your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, Microsoft is starting to work on aligning all the XAML dialects as "XAML standard".

```
https://github.com/Microsoft/xaml-standard
```

[image]

Comment: Until there's any evidence that XAML Standard is actually going anywhere they might as well just throw it in the cupboard with all their other aborted initiatives. Not even sure Microsoft really understand what they want out of it, let alone the rest of us.